# Is Huawei in app purchase the same version with the normal in app in purchase from android

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

I would to know is Huawei in app in purchase different in the way of coding from the normal in app in purchase from android?

If hes, do we have to recode the normal in app in purchase from android to Huawei version?

Comment: They both are different, for Huawei you'll have to use HMS Core SDK to integrate Huawei IAP in your app. See https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/codelab/HMSInAppPurchase/index.html#0

Comment: What is "normal"? You mean Google Play in-app purchase?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's a different way for appGallery (Huawei). I've implemented playstore and appgallery in app purchases in my app. I just separated the Implementations using flavors and the repository pattern as below.

```
productFlavors {
        googlePlay {
            versionCode 72
            versionName "1.6.2"

        }
        appGallery {
            versionCode 70
            versionName "1.5.9"
        }
 }
```

And then in my gradle file I added the custom implementations for appGallery and play store as below.

for appGallery

```
appGalleryImplementation 'com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-core:1.2.0.300'
appGalleryImplementation 'com.huawei.hms:iap:4.0.2.300'
```

for play store

```
googlePlayImplementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:3.0.0'
```

And then I created an interface, this interface needs to be implemented by both flavors.

```
interface PurchaseRepository : LifecycleObserver {
    fun provideActivity(activity: Activity)
    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
    fun onCreate()
    fun loadInventorySkus()
    fun purchaseItem(sku: String)
    fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?)
    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
    fun onDestroy()
    interface OwnedSkusPurchaseListener {
        fun onOwnedSkuLoaded(sku: Sku?)
    }
    interface PurchaseResultListener {
        fun onLoadingInventory()
        fun onCancelPurchase()
        fun onFailedPurchase(exception: Exception? = null)
        fun onOrderNotLogin()
        fun onSuccessPurchase()
        fun onInventoryLoaded(skus: List<Sku?>)
        fun onSkuAlreadyOwned()
    }
}
```

The implementation for app gallery looks like as below

```
class PurchaseRepositoryImpl(userEndpoints: UserEndpoints,
                         private val userRepositoryConfig: UserRepositoryConfig,
                         private val skus: List<String>) : BasePurchaseRepository(userEndpoints, userRepositoryConfig) {

override fun onCreate() {
    updateOwnedProducts()
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
        isSandBoxActivated()
}

override fun loadInventorySkus() {
    getSkuDetails(activity, skus, PRODUCT_TYPE_RENEWABLE_SUBSCRIPTION)
}

private fun updateOwnedProducts() {
    val task = Iap.getIapClient(activity).obtainOwnedPurchases(OwnedPurchasesReq().apply {
        priceType = PRODUCT_TYPE_RENEWABLE_SUBSCRIPTION
    })
    task.addOnSuccessListener { result ->
        if (result != null && result.inAppPurchaseDataList != null) {
            (0 until result.inAppPurchaseDataList.size).forEach { i ->
                val inAppPurchaseData = result.inAppPurchaseDataList[i]
                val inAppSignature = result.inAppSignature[i]

                val inAppPurchaseDataBean = InAppPurchaseData(inAppPurchaseData)
                val purchaseState = inAppPurchaseDataBean.purchaseState

                if (checkDeliverTransactionState(inAppPurchaseData, inAppSignature)
                        && purchaseState == InAppPurchaseData.PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
                    listenerProductSku?.onOwnedSkuLoaded(inAppPurchaseDataBean.toSku())
                } else
                    listenerProductSku?.onOwnedSkuLoaded(null)

                sendUpdatePurchase(inAppPurchaseData)
            }
        }
    }.addOnFailureListener {
        listenerProductSku?.onOwnedSkuLoaded(null)
    }
}

private fun isSandBoxActivated() {
    val client = Iap.getIapClient(activity)
    val task = client.isSandboxActivated(IsSandboxActivatedReq())
    task.addOnSuccessListener {
        if (it != null)
            Timber.d("Sandbox is activated")
    }.addOnFailureListener {
        if (it != null)
            Timber.e(it)
    }
}

override fun purchaseItem(sku: String) {
    val client: IapClient = Iap.getIapClient(activity)
    val task = client.createPurchaseIntent(createGetBuyIntentReq(PRODUCT_TYPE_RENEWABLE_SUBSCRIPTION, sku))
    task.apply {
        addOnSuccessListener { it ->
            it.status?.let {
                // you should pull up the page to complete the payment process
                startResolutionForResult(activity, it, REQ_CODE_BUY)
            }
        }
        addOnFailureListener {
            when (it) {
                is IapApiException -> {
                    val apiException = it
                    val returnCode = apiException.statusCode
                    listenerPurchaseResult?.onFailedPurchase(exception)
                    Timber.d("getBuyIntent, returnCode: $returnCode")
                }
                else -> Timber.e(it)
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun startResolutionForResult(activity: Activity, status: Status?, reqCode: Int) {
    if (status == null) {
        Timber.e("status is null")
        return
    }
    if (status.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            status.startResolutionForResult(activity, reqCode)
        } catch (exp: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
            listenerPurchaseResult?.onFailedPurchase(exp)
            Timber.e(exp)
        }
    } else {
        Timber.e("intent is null")
    }
}

private fun getSkuDetails(context: Context, skuList: List<String>, type: Int) {
    val client = Iap.getIapClient(context)
    val task = client.obtainProductInfo(createGetSkuDetailReq(type, ArrayList(skuList)))
    task.addOnSuccessListener { result ->
        if (result.productInfoList != null) {
            listenerPurchaseResult?.onInventoryLoaded(result.productInfoList.map { it.transform() })
        }
    }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
        if (exception is IapApiException) {
            val returnCode = exception.statusCode
            if (returnCode == OrderStatusCode.ORDER_HWID_NOT_LOGIN)
                listenerPurchaseResult?.onOrderNotLogin()
            else
                listenerPurchaseResult?.onFailedPurchase(exception)
        } else
            listenerPurchaseResult?.onFailedPurchase(exception)
    }
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode == REQ_CODE_BUY) {
        data?.let {
            val buyResultInfo = Iap.getIapClient(activity).parsePurchaseResultInfoFromIntent(data)
            when (buyResultInfo.returnCode) {
                OrderStatusCode.ORDER_STATE_CANCEL -> listenerPurchaseResult?.onCancelPurchase()
                OrderStatusCode.ORDER_PRODUCT_OWNED -> {
                    listenerPurchaseResult?.onSkuAlreadyOwned()
                    sendUpdatePurchase(buyResultInfo.inAppPurchaseData)
                }
                OrderStatusCode.ORDER_STATE_SUCCESS -> {
                    if (checkDeliverTransactionState(buyResultInfo.inAppPurchaseData, buyResultInfo.inAppDataSignature)) {
                        sendUpdatePurchase(buyResultInfo.inAppPurchaseData)
                        listenerPurchaseResult?.onSuccessPurchase()
                    } else
                        listenerPurchaseResult?.onFailedPurchase()
                }
                else -> listenerPurchaseResult?.onFailedPurchase()
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun checkDeliverTransactionState(appData: String, appSignature: String): Boolean {
    return CipherUtil.doCheck(appData, appSignature, API_KEY_HMS_IN_PURCHASE)
}

private fun sendUpdatePurchase(jsonAppPurchaseData: String?) {
    jsonAppPurchaseData?.let {
        val inAppPurchaseDataBean = InAppPurchaseData(jsonAppPurchaseData)
        userUpgradeRepository(inAppPurchaseDataBean.transform(userRepositoryConfig.uuid))
    }
}

private fun createGetSkuDetailReq(type: Int, skuList: ArrayList<String>): ProductInfoReq = ProductInfoReq().apply {
    productIds = skuList
    priceType = type
}

private fun createGetBuyIntentReq(type: Int, skuId: String?) = PurchaseIntentReq().apply {
    productId = skuId
    priceType = type
}
```

}

And the implementation for play store

```
 class PurchaseRepositoryImpl(userEndpoints: UserEndpoints,
                             private val userRepositoryConfig: UserRepositoryConfig,
                             private val skus: List<String>) : BasePurchaseRepository(userEndpoints, userRepositoryConfig) {

    private lateinit var checkout: ActivityCheckout
    private lateinit var inventory: Inventory
    private lateinit var selectedSku: String

    override fun onCreate() {
        checkout = Checkout.forActivity(activity, BaseApplication[activity].billing)
        checkout.start()
        checkout.createPurchaseFlow(PurchaseListener())
        loadInventorySkus()
    }

    override fun loadInventorySkus() {
        inventory = checkout.makeInventory()
        inventory.load(Inventory.Request.create()
                .loadAllPurchases()
                .loadSkus(ProductTypes.SUBSCRIPTION, skus), InventoryCallback())
    }

    override fun purchaseItem(sku: String) {
        checkout.whenReady(object : Checkout.EmptyListener() {
            override fun onReady(requests: BillingRequests) {
                selectedSku = sku
                requests.purchase(ProductTypes.SUBSCRIPTION, selectedSku, null, checkout.purchaseFlow)
            }
        })
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        checkout.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }

    private inner class PurchaseListener : EmptyRequestListener<Purchase>() {
        override fun onSuccess(purchase: Purchase) {
            if (purchase.state == Purchase.State.PURCHASED) {
                userUpgradeRepository(purchase.transform(userRepositoryConfig.getFirebaseId(), true))
                listenerPurchaseResult?.onSuccessPurchase()
            } else
                userUpgradeRepository(purchase.transform(userRepositoryConfig.getFirebaseId(), false))
        }

        override fun onError(response: Int, e: Exception) {
            if (e is BillingException) {
                when (e.response) {
                    ResponseCodes.ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED -> {
                        listenerPurchaseResult?.onSkuAlreadyOwned()
                        userUpgradeRepository(PurchaseInfo(
                                sku = selectedSku,
                                isPurchase = true
                        ))
                    }
                    ResponseCodes.USER_CANCELED -> listenerPurchaseResult?.onCancelPurchase()
                    else -> listenerPurchaseResult?.onFailedPurchase(e)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private inner class InventoryCallback : Inventory.Callback {
        override fun onLoaded(products: Inventory.Products) {
            try {
                val skuProducts = products[ProductTypes.SUBSCRIPTION].skus.toList()
                        .map { it.transform() }
                        .sortedBy { it.detailedPrice?.amount }

                listenerPurchaseResult?.onInventoryLoaded(skuProducts)

                skuProducts.forEach { sku ->
                    val isPurchased = products[ProductTypes.SUBSCRIPTION].hasPurchaseInState(sku.id?.code
                            ?: "", Purchase.State.PURCHASED)
                    if (isPurchased) listenerProductSku?.onOwnedSkuLoaded(sku)
                    if (!isPurchased && userRepositoryConfig.getTypeSubscription() == sku.id?.code)
                        userUpgradeRepository(sku.toPurchaseInfo(userRepositoryConfig.getFirebaseId(), isPurchased))
                }

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }}
```

Each repository implementation must be inside its respective flavor directory as below

[image]

These purchase repositories contain some business logic from my app, but I hope this answer might help you to understand how you can keep your app working
for app gallery and play store as well.

[IN APP PURCHASE HUAWEI CODE LAB](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/codelab/HMSInAppPurchase/index.html#0)